# Tags for packages/add-ons should come along with a "parent" tag?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags, edits

Is there any guideline to always include a "parent" tag when tagging a question with package/add-on tags?

For instance, there are many tags for specific R packages, such as[ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2), [knitr](/questions/tagged/knitr). Check the wiki excerpts:

> - ggplot2 is an actively maintained open-source chart-drawing library for R, written by Hadley Wickham, based upon the principles of "Grammar of Graphics". It partially replaces R's basic plot and the lattice package, while providing a clean, powerful, orthogonal and fun API.
> - knitr is an R package for dynamic report generation based on the concept of literate programming.

Does it make sense to have a question tagged any of these but not [r](/questions/tagged/r)?

The same question applies to many other tags, say, [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) for Python, tags "*.js" for Javascript...

Is it valid to edit these questions only to add the "parent" tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, the language tag should be applied. Sometimes a gem / egg / extension is so established and popular that it's not *really* needed - even COBOL programmers know that's a Python library, but in most cases it's nice to have. Rarely would the use of the parent language tag block another *essential* tag for the question, but it does happen once in a blue moon with some very framework specific questions.

Editing to add these tags is appreciated *provided* that you fix anything else that might need fixing on the post when you save the edit. We appreciate any good edit, we appreciate them *a lot* more when they're thorough. That's a general guideline and it's not really exclusive to tag edits.

Just edit with care and there shouldn't be a problem :)